# Onclick enlarge image inside a popup/dialog window

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, dialog

Is it possible to make an image appear larger in a popup window? This is an example of my picture that I am trying to expand: https://i.stack.imgur.com/grp1G.jpgnter This is what I mean by a popup/dialog box:EXAMPLE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WKqW.jpg The code I have so far is:

```
      <div id="graphSect" id = "pageone" data-role="main" class ="ui-content">
            <a href ="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">

                    <img src ="res/images/Capture.JPG"></a>

                    <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup"> 
                            <a href="pageone" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a><img src ="res/images/Capture.JPG" style="width:1200px;height:600px;" >
                    </div>
         </div>
```

but I would like to do something that resembles the example pic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like lightbox.
see examples in link below: 
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
Hope this might help.

Comment: is there a way to avoid lightbox?

Comment: well yes you can do it by yourself, but with lightbox it takes less than 1 min and it is compatible with all browsers, not sure that you can be as fast as this!  Personally I can't :)
But if you want to code something like this, you can try and you ll maybe need to use a Jquery UI dialig with your bigger image inside or something like that

Comment: Did you found a solution?